# SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.2'

Tags: freebsd, openssl, apache-2.4

I'm using `FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE` with `apache24-2.4.10_2` package.

```
[root@alexus ~]# uname -a
FreeBSD alexus.org 9.2-RELEASE-p5 FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE-p5 #0 r265974: Wed May 14 07:57:04 PDT 2014     root@jj3.myibay.com:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/R610  amd64
[root@alexus ~]# httpd -V | head -1
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (FreeBSD)
[root@alexus ~]#
```

I'm trying to enable `TLSv1.2` and I'm getting following error while restarting `apache24` service:

`SSLProtocol        all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 +TLSv1 +TLSv1.2`

```
[root@alexus /usr/local/etc/apache24/Includes]# service apache24 restart
Performing sanity check on apache24 configuration:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 5 of /usr/local/etc/apache24/Includes/ssl_module.conf:
SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.2'
[root@alexus /usr/local/etc/apache24/Includes]#
```

`openssl` comes with FreeBSD and then I installed newer version as package as well.

```
[root@alexus ~]# openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
[root@alexus ~]# /usr/local/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
[root@alexus ~]#
```

What am I doing wrong? As of now I had to fallback to `TLSv1`, is there a way to actually enable it?

*** UPDATE ***

```
[root@alexus ~]# ldd /usr/local/libexec/apache24/mod_ssl.so
/usr/local/libexec/apache24/mod_ssl.so:
    libssl.so.6 => /usr/lib/libssl.so.6 (0x801236000)
    libcrypto.so.6 => /lib/libcrypto.so.6 (0x8014a0000)
    libcrypt.so.5 => /lib/libcrypt.so.5 (0x8018a5000)
    libthr.so.3 => /lib/libthr.so.3 (0x801ac8000)
    libc.so.7 => /lib/libc.so.7 (0x800824000)
[root@alexus ~]#
```

Comment: Sounds like Apache got built against the old version of OpenSSL rather than the new one.

Comment: First, you should upgrade your system to 9.2-RELEASE-p11 (`freebsd-update` can do this unless you custom built world) - also fair warning that 9.2 will be unsupported at the end of the year, 9.3 is an extended support release if you don't want to keep pace. Run `ldd /usr/local/libexec/apache24/mod_ssl.so` to see what `libssl.so` it was built against, should be the one in `/usr/local/lib`)

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but why are you trying to explicitly add `tlsv1.2` if you start with `all`?  Isn't that automatically if your system supports it?

Comment: @Zoredache Yes, `all` includes `+SSLv2 +SSLv3 +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2` *if those protocols are supported by the library*. It's useful to explicitly tack the `+TLSv1.2` on there as it will throw errors if it's not supported.

Comment: @MichaelHampton & @ChrisS is right, package was build against old version of `libssl.so`, I assume older version of openssl doesn't have support for `TLSv1.2` or `TLSv1.1`, only `TLSv1`.

Comment: Yep. TLSv1.1 and 1.2 was introduced in 1.0.1, the old 0.9.x branch only supports 1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@MichaelHampton & @ChrisS is right:

This cannot be done as `/usr/local/libexec/apache24/mod_ssl.so` linked against older version of openssl `/usr/lib/libssl.so.6`.

```
[root@alexus ~]# ldd /usr/local/libexec/apache24/mod_ssl.so
/usr/local/libexec/apache24/mod_ssl.so:
    libssl.so.6 => /usr/lib/libssl.so.6 (0x801236000)
    libcrypto.so.6 => /lib/libcrypto.so.6 (0x8014a0000)
    libcrypt.so.5 => /lib/libcrypt.so.5 (0x8018a5000)
    libthr.so.3 => /lib/libthr.so.3 (0x801ac8000)
    libc.so.7 => /lib/libc.so.7 (0x800824000)
[root@alexus ~]#
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the official packaged version is compiled, but you can explicitly tell the ports system to compile again the base OpenSSL or the Ports OpenSSL by specifying `WITH_OPENSSL_BASE= yes` or `WITH_OPENSSL_PORTS= yes` in `/etc/make.conf` (respectively).

Comment: @ChrisS thanks, but unfortunately since I'm using packages and not ports this won't help me( but thanks anyway)

Comment: I was wondering if it makes sense to try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and/or `LD_PRELOAD` via `mod_env` to load another `openssl`?